# Response.Redirect("XXX", false) and Page Life Cycle?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Due to performance reason I am using, `Response.Redirect("XXX", false)`. I don't want page-life-cycle to continue. Is there is any way to use  `Response.Redirect("XXX", false)`(note the **false**) and stop page life-cycle in the same time. See the performace issue,

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2009/06/25/correct-use-of-system-web-httpresponse-redirect.aspx

http://mvolo.com/fix-the-3-high-cpu-performance-problems-for-iis-aspnet-apps/

Comment: Well, the most logical way would be to use Response.Redirect("XXX", true). Could you provide the reason why you can't use that ? The context might help to find the answer.

Comment: Why do you want to stop the current  page life-cycle? @cahmadzadeh: I assume because the [`true` overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt.aspx) is not recommended due to performance reasons.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, Yes definitely this create scabality issues. http://mvolo.com/fix-the-3-high-cpu-performance-problems-for-iis-aspnet-apps/

Answer (score 3):

You can always use Response.End(), but the easiest way is to simply pass the true argument.

```
Response.Redirect("XXX", true);
```

Or

```
Response.Redirect("XXX", false);
Response.End();
```

**EDIT:**
After reading comments on your post, it seems like Response.End() will not be useful either, because it will also throw a ThreadAbortException.

It seems however that the best answer is given here (use HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest instead of response end, but it will not stop the page lifecycle): http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312629/en

```
Response.Redirect("XXX", false);
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

Best thing to do if you do not want the exception is to then exit gracefully in your code.

Comment: FYI, it does not stop page life-cycle.